# Can I check in and go through security at DTW the night before a flight?

Tags: airports, airport-security, american-airlines, check-in, detroit

I have a 6 am domestic flight out of DTW on American Airlines.  Can I check in and go through airport the night before?

Alternatively, I am happy to go standby for a flight at 7:20 or 9:00 the night before if this is a better way to pursue this; would this work?

If I will not be allowed through security, may I hang out in the lobby until 12 am (it is a 24 hr open airport) then go through security (I will check in online 24 hr before)? Really, I am looking for a way to avoid getting a hotel.

Comment: According to [this link](http://www.sleepinginairports.net/usa/detroit.htm) DTW is open 24h.

Comment: Usually check-in opens around 3h before departure time.

Comment: You should be allowed through security no problem. It's checking your bags (if any) that you would have to wait for. Check to see if there are better food options inside/outside security.

Comment: Check-in for American Airlines domestic flights opens 24 hours before. However, checking luggage is limited to something like 4 hours before departure. Some airports sweep and close the secure areas after the last flight departs; others let you stay in. I do not know how DTW works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How early can you go through airport security for an International flight?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10905/how-early-can-you-go-through-airport-security-for-an-international-flight)

Answer (score 2):

I do not know whether DTW will let you stay inside security overnight. Some airports sweep and close the secure area after the last flight departs; others effectively stay open 24 hours.

You can check in for an American Airlines domestic flight at 24 hours prior to departure. If you have a smart phone, you can display your boarding pass on your phone as soon as you check in. You cannot check luggage more than about 4 hours prior to departure.

Most airlines will *not* allow you to stand by for a flight the night before. American has a same day flight change, but I think the limit is 6 hours earlier or later so I don't think that will help you get out the night before.