# Is it possible to avoid overstaying by entering airport earlier than flight?

Tags: air-travel, legal, airports, overstaying

By some misfortune and bad luck I ended with Schengen visa of 8 stay days and the flight back is one day later. So, I shall have one day overstay.
Does it have any sense to show up in the airport one day early, so that I stay within stay day limits?

Comment: Can't hurt to try.  The hardest bit is going to be getting through security whenyour boarding pass has tomorrow's date on it.

Comment: Yeah, it may cause some eyebrow rise :) Or maybe I could go to the embassy / consulate / police station and explain to them the situation?? Thanks for answer

Comment: I'm not talking about eyebrows.  Immigration is after the security checkpoint where you show your pass.  There may be a policy of not letting people in if their flight is too far in the future.  If you haven't already called the consulate that issued your visa, do that.  They may be able to extend its validity by one day.

Comment: Thanks once again, I will do that first thing tomorrow morning!

Comment: It would probably help if you told us the airport you're leaving from (some are not even open overnight!), and what time your flight is.

Comment: @jcaron the poster's previous question indicates that he will be in Prague.

Comment: @jcaron - I shall be in Prague. One more issue also bothering me a lot is initial departure: is it possible that during first check, when I am arriving in Prague from Kiev, the border control does not let me in at all noticing that stay days are less than flight date by one day? :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to avoid overstaying you'll have to clear border control exit checks before 23:59:59 on the last visa validity day. It might make sense to arrive (very) early in the airport in order to make the cutoff time. However the problem is that border control checkpoints are usually located *after* airport security checks. So the question really becomes: [how early before my flight can I go through airport security checks?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10905/how-early-can-you-go-through-airport-security-for-an-international-flight)

The access to security checks is likely to be regulated by flight departure time. So is check-in, although you can always do that online and be alright if you don't have any hold-luggage to drop off. Keep in mind that you'll need a boarding pass to be allowed through security. I couldn't find any definite answer on the topic, and some forum posts seem to say that this is airport dependent. Personally I would call the airport and ask, not mentioning the overstaying issue but rather saying for example that you have an early departure and don't want to sleep in a hotel. I would also turn up at the airport and try my luck anyway.

As a final note make sure you make it through security checks at a reasonable time, i.e. one that is compatible with the opening hours of border controls. Indeed these might not be manned 24h, so you want to make sure that you arrive at the right time.

Comment: At VIE this early December, I checked in online, printed Boarding pass, no checked in Luggage, Security just warned me that your flight is after 9 hours, and if you pass here, you can not come back.